# Apache CXF REST Services w/ Spring AOP

Tags: aop, cxf, jax-rs, spring-aop

I'm trying to get Apache CXF JAX-RS services working with Spring AOP. I've created a simple logging class:

```
public class AOPLogger {

    public void logBefore(){
        System.out.println("Logging Before!");
    }

}
```

My Spring configuration (beans.xml):

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aopLogger" ref="test.aop.AOPLogger">
        <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut="execution(* test.rest.RestService.*(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="aopLogger" class="test.aop.AOPLogger"/>
```

I always get an NPE in RestService when a call is made to a Method getServletRequest(), which has:

```
return messageContext.getHttpServletRequest();
```

If I remove the aop configuration or comment it out from my beans.xml, everything works fine.

All of my actual Rest services extend test.rest.RestService (which is a class) and call getServletRequest().  I'm just trying to just get AOP up and running based off of the example in the CXF JAX-RS documentation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have your resource class implementing some simple interface with a method

@Context
void setMessageContext(MessageContext mc) {}

this will enable the CXF SpringAOPHelper to discover the method